# How to change a sprites image on trigger?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am specifically trying to change a doors sprite image from closed to open when I interact with a key. I have been able to make it work where the keys sprite image changes to the open door sprite but haven't been able to find a solution to change a specific named gameObject's sprite.

```
  private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = portal;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding a solution that worked for me.

Thanks everyone!

[Answer Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity2D/comments/346awj/how_do_you_change_the_sprite_of_another_object/)

GameObject.Find("game Object Name").GetComponent().sprite = portal;

Answer (score 1):

you can use the animation and  set on the trigger at the animator after that just add to the script, ex: isOpen

```
Animator anim;
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
anim.setTrigger("isOpen");
enter code here
}
```